# Operator overloading crash

Tags: c++

So I'm following along with this book called SDL Game Development by Shaun Mitchell. I've ran into a few hiccups with code from the book but have so far been able to figure it out and correct on my own but this one has got me in a bind.

The program compiles fine but crashes with a seg fault.

This is the Vector2D class that the book has me write:

```
#ifndef __Vector2D__
#define __Vector2D__

#include <math.h>

class Vector2D
{
public:
    Vector2D(float x, float y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}

    float getX() { return m_x; }
    float getY() { return m_y; }

    void setX(float x) { m_x = x; }
    void setY(float y) { m_y = y; }

    float length() { return sqrt(m_x * m_x + m_y * m_y); }
    Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D& v2) const
    {
        return Vector2D(m_x + v2.m_x, m_y + v2.m_y);
    }
    friend Vector2D& operator+=(Vector2D& v1, const Vector2D& v2)
    {
        v1.m_x += v2.m_x;
        v1.m_y += v2.m_y;

        return v1;
    }
    Vector2D operator*(float scalar)
    {
        return Vector2D(m_x * scalar, m_y * scalar);
    }
    Vector2D& operator*=(float scalar)
    {
        m_x *= scalar;
        m_y *= scalar;

        return *this;
    }
    Vector2D operator-(const Vector2D& v2) const
    {
        return Vector2D(m_x - v2.m_x, m_y - v2.m_y);
    }
    friend Vector2D& operator-=(Vector2D& v1, const Vector2D& v2)
    {
        v1.m_x -= v2.m_x;
        v1.m_y -= v2.m_y;

        return v1;
    }
    Vector2D operator/(float scalar)
    {
        return Vector2D(m_x / scalar, m_y / scalar);
    }
    Vector2D& operator/=(float scalar)
    {
        m_x /= scalar;
        m_y /= scalar;

        return *this;
    }
    void normalize()
    {
        float l = length();
        if (l > 0)
        {
            (*this) *= 1 / 1;
        }
    }
private:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
};

#endif // __Vector2D__
```

This is a Player class' input handling event where the program begins to crash:

```
void Player::handleInput()
{
    Vector2D* vec = TheInputHandler::Instance()->getMousePosition();

    m_velocity = (*vec - m_position) / 100;
}
```

It crashes at m_velocity = (*vec - m_position) / 100; which of course traces back to my Vector2D class' operator-. m_velocity and m_position are both Vector2Ds. Replacing the - with + produces the same crash.

Any help with what may be wrong would be super appreciated.

Comment: *which of course traces back to my Vector2D class' operator-* it doesn't per se: it is much more likely that getMousePosition() returns nullptr or other garbage, which you then dereference, which is undefined behaviour and results in segfault

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also knowing what kind of "crash" you're talking about would be helpful, even if it's good old "Segment fault, core dumped."

Comment: Show the definition of `getMousePosition`. It could be returning a pointer to a local variable, which could cause a problem like this.

Comment: `(*this) *= 1 / 1;` ? Are you sure?

Comment: @BetaCarotin I'm just following what's written in the book.

Comment: @Barry Very difficult to do since I'm mid book and everything is kind of still mish mashy

Comment: @JimmyAlexander Probably less difficult than it would be for us to answer the question without sufficient information.

Comment: Vector2D* getMousePosition()
    {
        return m_mousePosition;
    }

m_mousePosition is a private Vector2D pointer

Comment: No idea what the problem was or why the book had me use a pointer for that but I just converted m_mousePosition to a non pointer Vector2D and everything is working now.

Comment: If the code you posted is from a book, throw it away. There are some horrible mistakes in there.

Comment: @BetaCarotin [link](http://www.amazon.com/SDL-Game-Development-Black-White/dp/1849696829/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8

Answer (score -3):

```
Vector2D* vec = TheInputHandler::Instance()->getMousePosition();
```

You made it a pointer, but never allocated memory for it. (unless that's what that function does..?)

There is no need to make this a pointer if you're not going to pass it anywhere.

Comment: If that function doesn't return a pointer to an existing vector, what else could it be doing?

Comment: @DanielSaad you're probably right in saying this shouldn't return a pointer (especially since the object is a simple POD with only two floats), but this does not provide an answer to the question

Comment: No idea what the problem was or why the book had me use a pointer for that but I just converted m_mousePosition to a non pointer Vector2D and everything is working now.